# SQL - joining on recursive table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

it has been a time for me since doing SQL, so I just want to ask for help with this one.

I would like a solution without temp table if possible, but better than nothing ofc, would be glad for every solution! Not really sure if this is possible without it...

I have two tables.

Table Premise

| premise_id | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 6 |

Table Category - this is just slice coresponding to the above premise_id 3. I need for every premise to get it's category **AND all of it's parents.**

| id | parent_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 17 | nameA |
| 17 | 11 | nameB |
| 11 | 5 | nameC |
| 5 | null | nameD |

**The RESULT should look like this:**

| premise_id | category_id | category_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 20 | nameA |
| 3 | 17 | nameB |
| 3 | 11 | nameC |
| 3 | 5 | nameD |

All I managed to write is this recursive query for getting the tree inside category:

```sql
with recursive categories as (
    select id, id_path, parent_id, name from category
    union all
    select c.id, c.id_path, c.parent_id, c.name from category c 
    join categories ctgs on ctgs.parent_id = c.id
) select * from categories
;
```

Getting lazy, will do prtscreens now. It results fine like this. There IS the parents-path itself, as `id_path`, but would not like to rely on that. Worth noting is that not always the children has higher ID than parent !

[image]

----------
But I am not really sure how to join it. Feels like I am missing something really obvious, but really, what is the join condition on this? Or should I go with temp table? I am using **Mariadb 10.5.**

Thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your recursive query to produce rows with category id and ancestor category id (so multiple rows for each category id); the path isn't as easily joinable, and the id/parent id aren't enough to join with a single id and get all the ancestors.

So something like:

```
with recursive category_ancestors as (
    select id as category_id, id as ancestor_id from category
    union all
    select category_id, parent_id
    from category_ancestors
    join category on category.id=ancestor_id
    where parent_id is not null
)
select premise_id, ancestor_id
from premise
join category_ancestors using (category_id)
```

(obviously joining again to category to get the name if you need that)

Comment: Thank you man, this works, solution is perfect for me. Just for clearance I am posting the SQL with the join. ```

Comment: Nope, i am not - just thanx ))